# Javascript arrays not working in some instances for WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm working on a OBJ file reader for WebGL and I'm having problems rendering the read triangles. 
When I try to draw the triangles I get this error: `[Error] WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawArrays: attempt to access out of bounds arrays` This is my source code:

```
function ObjModel(filename, shader, gl) {
  var readVertices = {}, readUVs = {}, readNormals = {};
  var verticesIdx = 0, uvIndices = 0, normalIndices = 0;

  var tmpVertices = {}, tmpUVs = {}, tmpNormals = {};
  var tmpVerticesIdx = 0;

  this.components = {};

  loadFileAsText(filename, (result) => {
    if(lines[i][0] == "v" && lines[i][1] == " ") {
        var floats = lines[i].split(" ");

        readVertices[verticesIdx + 0] = parseFloat(floats[1]);
        readVertices[verticesIdx + 1] = parseFloat(floats[2]);
        readVertices[verticesIdx + 2] = parseFloat(floats[3]);

        verticesIdx += 3;
      }

      if(lines[i][0] == "f") {
        var points = lines[i].split(" ");
        var point1 = points[1].split("/");
        var point2 = points[2].split("/");
        var point3 = points[3].split("/");


        tmpVertices[tmpVerticesIdx + 0] = readVertices[parseInt(point1[0]) - 1];
        tmpVertices[tmpVerticesIdx + 1] = readVertices[parseInt(point2[0]) - 1];
        tmpVertices[tmpVerticesIdx + 2] = readVertices[parseInt(point3[0]) - 1];

        tmpUVs[tmpVerticesIdx + 0] = readUVs[parseInt(point1[1]) - 1];
        tmpUVs[tmpVerticesIdx + 1] = readUVs[parseInt(point2[1]) - 1];
        tmpUVs[tmpVerticesIdx + 2] = readUVs[parseInt(point3[1]) - 1];

        tmpNormals[tmpVerticesIdx + 0] = readNormals[parseInt(point1[2]) - 1];
        tmpNormals[tmpVerticesIdx + 1] = readNormals[parseInt(point2[2]) - 1];
        tmpNormals[tmpVerticesIdx + 2] = readNormals[parseInt(point3[2]) - 1];

        tmpVerticesIdx += 3;
      }
    }


    this.components[0] = new ObjComponent(tmpVertices, tmpUVs, tmpNormals);


    this.cluster = new TriangleCluster(this.components[0].vertices, this.components[0].uvs, this.components[0].normals, 1, shader, gl);
  });
}
```

The interesting part are the last two lines. The `ObjComponent` is this simple class:

```
function ObjComponent(vertices, uvs, normals) {
  this.vertices = vertices;
  this.uvs = uvs;
  this.normals = normals;
}
```

That just contains the arrays for the vertices, uns and normals. The `TriangleCluster` is the class that draws the triangles. 
With this code I get the errors message from above but setting the arrays by my self to some values works, so the somehow the arrays don't work. But I can access the elements of the `tmpVertices`. I printed the array content inside the render function of the `TriangleCluster` and the data is still ok

This is my `TriangleCluster` class:

```
function TriangleCluster(vertices, uvs, normals, triangleNumber, shader, gl) {
  shader.use();


  this.vertices = vertices;
  this.uvs = uvs;
  this.normals = normals;


  var verticesBuffer = new ArrayBufferFloat(this.vertices, gl);
  var verticesAttribLocation = new VertexAttribPointerFloat(shader.getProgram(), "vertex", 3, 3, 0, gl);

  var uvsBuffer = new ArrayBufferFloat(this.uvs, gl);
  var uvsAttribLocation = new VertexAttribPointerFloat(shader.getProgram(), "uv", 2, 2, 0, gl);

  var normalsBuffer = new ArrayBufferFloat(this.normals, gl);
  var normalsAttribLocation = new VertexAttribPointerFloat(shader.getProgram(), "normal", 3, 3, 0, gl);

  this.render = function() {
    verticesBuffer.bind();
    verticesAttribLocation.bind();
    uvsBuffer.bind();
    uvsAttribLocation.bind();
    normalsBuffer.bind();
    normalsAttribLocation.bind();

    this.texture.activate(gl.TEXTURE0);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, triangleNumber * 3);
  }
}
```

Could this behavior come from my `ArrayBuffer` class, where I create a `new Float32Array` that it doesn't work with the `parseFloat`?

So where is the problem, in the code?

Comment: It's impossible to tell where the issues are but. (1) UVs are *usually* only 2 values per entry (2) indices in obj files can be relative (3) uvs and texcoords are both optional (4) check that your parts `tempVertices`, `tempUVs`, `tempNormals` actually make sense before you send them to WebGL. I'd suggest you look through the three.js obj loader source or [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-load-obj.html). Also, verify some [other loader](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+obj+viewer) loads your .OBJ file just to validate that others are able to load it.

Comment: @gman Obviously UVs are only 2D but this is where the faces are are made and every face with n vertices has n UVs. This isn't the whole code, because the rest really would inflate this question and doesn't contribute much to it. I checked the arrays and they have valid elements. This loader is my attempt to port my C++ OBJ loader to WebGL and JS so everything else should work.

Comment: But you already said it doesn't work therefore your data is not correct. The arrays are not the correct size or you setup your attributes wrong. Voting to close because you have not provided the required [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How should I check the data? I printed the data and it had the correct values. Also creating reproducible examples with OpenGL is nearly impossible, because there is so much setup and other stuff that is unrelated but required for a working code. What do you need to know?

Comment: Just guessing, maybe You can check if the obj' file is containing only triangles, not quads.

Comment: @deblocker it only does and because I only draw one triangle it shouldn't even matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that for some reason JS doesn't like the array conversions.